# VB.net - how do i get the response data from a website?

Tags: vb.net, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to build a program that post data using "httpRequest.Post()" and am also trying to get the response data of the website, how do i go about it:

```
httpRequest.Referer = "https://website.com/"
Dim value As String = Regex.Match(httpRequest.[Get]("https://website.com/Login", Nothing).ToString(), "<input name=""Token"" type=""hidden"" value=""(.*?)"" />").Groups(1).ToString()
httpRequest.AddParam("Token", value)
httpRequest.AddParam("memberId", array(0))
httpRequest.AddParam("password", array(1))
httpRequest.AddParam("exp", "retail")
Dim text2 As String = httpResponse.Post("https://website/Login").ToString

If text2.Contains(" "Success" : true ") Or text2.Contains(" "memberPasswordValidationError" : false ") Then
    If text2.Contains(" "Success" : true" ) Then
        Me.successCode1 = "welcome"
    ElseIf text2.Contains(" "memberPasswordValidationError" : false ") Then
        Me.successCode2 = "Fail"
    End If
End If
```

the response data looks like this

{
   "memberPasswordValidationError" : false,
   "Error" : null,
   "Success" : false
}

Comment: It looks like your already getting a response: the `json` you posted.

Comment: i only posted an example of how the response code should be. i dont know if im to use httpResponse or httpRequest

Comment: TBH if you are sending back json, why not deserialize this json object into a .net class object that *represents* this data? You shouldn't be using `Contains` on fields like that to check your data; inefficient, error prone and not reliable.

Comment: `trying to get the response data of the website, how do i go about it`, but then you mention `the response data looks like this`, I am confused on what you are asking. Are you getting the json back or no? I believe this may be a debugging issue here...

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern I have followed is

```
    'Imports System.Net
    Dim site As String
    site = String.Format("https://website/Login?{0}={1}&{2}={3}&{4}={5}&{6}={7}",
                         "Token", "tokenvalue",
                         "memberId", "val",
                         "password", "passwd value",
                         "exp", "retail")

    Dim request As WebRequest

    request = WebRequest.Create(site)
    request.Method = "POST" '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Dim data() As Byte = {}

    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    request.ContentLength = data.Length

    Dim stream As IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    stream.Close()

    Dim response As WebResponse
    response = request.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim s As String
    s = sr.ReadToEnd
```

**You'll need to change some of this to match your variables.  Hope it helps.**